# deleting record without button_to helper using jquery/coffee script

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, xmlhttprequest

I can't figure out how to destroy a record on click using coffee script/jquery. Normally I would use button_to rails helper but under the circumstances I can't.

```
<form id="instance_delete" action="<%= url_for my_url_delete_path(current_user.id, delete_this.id) %>" 
data-remote="true" method="delete"><%= link_to "Delete", "#", id: "delete_record_button"%> </form>


($ '#delete_record_button').click (e) =>
   e.preventDefault()
   ($ e.target.form).submit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little hack in the HTTP verbs since not all browsers uses (respects?) the standard HTTP verbs:

```
$('#delete_record_button').click (e) =>
   e.preventDefault()
   $.post(
     '#{path_to_update_action}',
     { user_id: #{current_user.id}, id: #{delete_this.id}, '_destroy': true },
     handler
     )
```

Where handler can either be an anonymous function or a defined callback.

I used the extra POST params `_destroy` set to `true` in order to send a destroy call on the record.

---

If you don't want Rails to recompile your assets each time the view/coffeescript is used (on Linux systems: insignificant, on Windows: VERY significant), you can use this workaround:

```
# haml file or seperated files but both included:
:javascript
  var path_to_update_action = "#{path_to_update_action}";
  var current_user_id = #{current_user.id};
  var id_to_delete = #{delete_this.id};

:coffeescript
  $('#delete_record_button').click (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    $.post(
      path_to_update_action,
      { user_id: current_user_id, id: id_to_delete, '_destroy': true },
      handler)
```

---

References :

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html (Ctrl+F "_destroy")

Comment: I have my coffee script in the assets pipeline, so I don't think I have access to rails helpers/variables. Will the coffee script pull the variables via .click event?

Comment: It has access to the helpers/variables. The thing is that Rails will recompile the JS asset everytime you hit the action, in order to use Ruby code in the JS. There is workaround for this, I update my answer